# Create multiple task using for each loop in sequential workflow SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow-tasks-list, custom-workflow

I need to create  a task for which I have used `create task` from the toolbox in visual studio 2016 .

In the event handler of create task I used for each loop to insert task for multiple approvers but it is only inserting the last record from foreach not all records.

Any body has gone through such requirement please let me know how to do it.